# Why we need LINQ even its also using query in background

Tags: linq-to-sql

Why we need LINQ? tho it's also generating query in background and executing in SQL, that we can do manually.

Any real time example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL, you don't particularly *need* LINQ.  You could do all the same stuff it does if you wanted to.  It just happens to be more convenient with LINQ in a couple of ways:

- You end up with an `IEnumerable` that you don't have to care about the inner workings of.  Just iterate over it much as you would a list or array.  No code required to fetch rows, update cursors, etc.
- From a consumer's point of view, that `IEnumerable` works the same as a query on *objects*, which is one of the places where LINQ really shines.  You can replace one with the other, and the rest of the code need never know.

Answer (score 1):

linq is not only related to database ,you can apply linq to list , array or any collection of data .....